# Cocos2D Deform object

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm new to cocos2D, and I wanna add an object that can be deformed when i touch it, can I do that on a CCSprite ? if yes, can anybody tell me how ? 
 thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skew a CCSprite with the [CCSkewTo/CCSkewBy](http://learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_skew_to.html) actions. Combine that with rotation and scaling that's about the most deformation you can get without getting hardcore on render textures, polygon tesselation or shader programming.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can do that on a CCSprite.

Comment: mmm can i do it with any other object on cocos2D ?